# How can I check if an element (h2) is really the first element inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to "manage" the first h2 element inside a div, only if it's really the "first element"

```
<div id="test">
    <h2>Try 1</h2>
    Test Test Test
    <h2>Try 2</h2>
</div>
```

here only h2 with text "Try 1" must be managed

```
<div id="test">
    Test Test Test
    <h2>Try 1</h2>
    <h2>Try 2</h2>
</div>
```

Here no (there is text before).

How can I do it with jQuery?

Comment: In your first example, there is also a text node before the `<h2>` element.

Comment: #test is the parent...of course...

Comment: How do you a draw a distinction between the leading text node in the first example and the text node in the second example? (In the second example, the text node is "`Test Test Test`"; in the first example the text node is "`    `".) I assume you want to match on non-whitespace in your leading text node?

Comment: @apsillers : I don't get your point! First example first node is h2. In the second, first "node" (also if it is not a node) is plain text. But ok, first node is not h2, so this is a different case...

Comment: No, in your first example, the first ***element*** node is `<h2>`. The first *node* is the leading whitespace. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cnxfe/) to demonstrate the difference.

Comment: Nice, I was hoping jQuery can manage this (working thinking at "real elements, not whytespace")...

Comment: @markzzz under normal Circumstances yes, you would just check the first element against a h2 tag, but your invalid markup 'test test test' is not wrapped in any element

Comment: @Philip Putting text in a `div` is not invalid markup ... is it?? You can create text nodes wherever you like as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would filter to get only the header that is the first node, ignoring all blank text nodes:-

```
$("#test").children("h2").first().filter(function() {

    var childNodes = this.parentNode.childNodes;
    var i = 0;
    var textNode = 3;

    // No children
    if(!childNodes.length) {
        return false;
    }

    // Skip blank text node
    if(childNodes[i].nodeType === textNode && childNodes[i].textContent.trim().length === 0) {
        i ++;
    }

    // Check we have a match
    return childNodes[i] === this;

});
```

Here is it in action http://jsfiddle.net/nmeXw/

Answer (score 4):

No jquery needed for that, just take:

```
document.getElementById('test').firstChild.nodeName // gives the name of the node
```

This will give you the name of the very first node, even if it's not a tag but just a plain text-node!

optionally you could of course use `document.querySelector()` if you want to be more flexible with your selectors and know that most of the clients browser support it.

To be clear: if you add a newline, this will also be considered as a text-node, so the heading needs to start on the same line or you will get `#text` as result for both examples!

This will fail:

```
<div id="test">
    <h2>Try 1</h2>
    Test Test Test
    <h2>Try 2</h2>
</div>
```

and this will work:

```
<div id="test"><h2>Try 1</h2>
    Test Test Test
    <h2>Try 2</h2>
</div>
```

[a little demo for you](http://jsfiddle.net/m8VUE/4/)

Comment: This will probably result in `"#text"` for both examples.

Comment: I want to use jQuery, as specified (as example, if I have .test element and not #test)

Comment: Well, I suppose jQuery helps developers on "avoid" this deep problem... (also because :first won't work anywhere).

Answer (score 2):

The challenge we're facing here is that javascript recognizes whitespace as a text node as well. Therefore, from a javascript point of view, this HTML:

```
<div id="test">
    <h2>Try 1</h2>    
    Test Test Test    
    <h2>Try 2</h2>
</div>
```

Is different from this HTML:

```
<div id="test"><h2>Try 1</h2>    
    Test Test Test    
    <h2>Try 2</h2>
</div>
```

In the first case, the first node inside the `div` is a textNode (`nodeType == 3`)
In the second HTML example, the first node inside the `div` is a `h2` node.

I've come up with a solution for this, a handy function that loops through all elements combining jQuery and native javascript.

## Solution

```
var objNodes = $(".wrapper").contents().get();

  function loopNodes(objNodes, i) {
    i = (typeof i === "undefined") ? 0 : i;

    if (objNodes[i].nodeType !== 3) {
      return {"isHeader":true, "first":$(objNodes[i])};

    } else {
      var strText = objNodes[i].innerText || objNodes[i].textContent;
      if ($.trim(strText).length === 0) {
        return loopNodes(objNodes, i+1);

      } else {
        return {"isHeader":false, "first":null};

      }
    }
  }
```

## Usage

```
var objResults = loopNodes(objNodes);
if (objResults.isHeader) {
    console.log("Coolness");
    objResults.first.text("AWESOME FIRST HEADER!"); 
} else {
    console.log("Less Coolness");
}
```

In action:
http://jsbin.com/welcome/61883/edit

Edit: Added the cross-browser way of getting innerText/textContent. See [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html) for full reference on the matter.

Comment: Give me some time, I've almost figured this out.

Comment: Meanwhile, check my solution :P

Comment: I understand my first answer was a -1, but this update should fix that.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found myself a [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Gg6Z3/6/), a bit funny :

```
if($.trim($('#test').html()).substr(0,4).toLowerCase() == "<h2>")
{
    $('#test h2:first').css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

What do you think about? :)

Comment: Unconventional but short and it works! Wouldn't work if your `h2` had any attributes, though. Maybe try `...substr(0,3).toLowerCase() == "<h2")`

Comment: apsillers suggestion to use contents looks better, but nonetheless pretty short (even if not very robust)

Comment: actually Stuart Wakefields Solution is the cleanest I would say.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to conditionally ignore leading nodes that are only whitespace text. Then see if the first node is an `<h2>` ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uQmpF/1)):

```
function isFirstChildH2(selector) {
    // get th efirst node, which may be a text node
    var firstNode = $(selector).contents().first();

    // if the first node is all whitespace text, ignore it and go to the next
    if(firstNode[0].nodeType == 3 && firstNode.text().match(/\S/g) == null) {
        firstNode = firstNode.next();
    }

    if(firstNode.is("h2")) {
        // it's an h2; do your magic!
        alert("h2 is the first thing on " + selector)
     } else {
        // first node is either non-whitespace text or an non-h2 element
        // don't do your magic
        alert("h2 is NOT the first thing on " + selector)
     }
}

isFirstElementH2("#test");
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's mix some jQuery with plain DOM code (as jQuery is not capable of handling [text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Text)):

```
var $el = $("#test > h2:first-child");
if (!$el.length) return false;
var el = $el.get(0),
    reg = /\S/; // no whitespace
for (var prev = el; prev = prev.previousSibling; )
    if (prev.nodeType == 3 && reg.test(prev.data))
        return false;
return el;
```

[Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/VssVL/1/)

Comment: Good answer, but I'm still bewildered why the OP would want invalid markup in his page :?